# How to declare Integer[] like array in strings.xml

Tags: android, integer

I want make this:

```
 Integer[] imageID = {
            R.drawable.farm_small,
            R.drawable.scroll_small,
            R.drawable.desert_small,
            R.drawable.bg_blue_small,
            R.drawable.city_small,
            R.drawable.clip_small,
            R.drawable.grass_small,
            R.drawable.green_leaves_small,
            R.drawable.moon_landscape_small,
            R.drawable.prismatic_floruish_small,
            R.drawable.technologic_small,
            R.drawable.white_small,
            R.drawable.red_small,
            R.drawable.bllue_small,
            R.drawable.yellow_small
    };
```

I use Integer[] in a class and also i was create it when the fragment is running, so that take something of time

like this:

```
<string-array name="background_name">
        <item>Farm Land</item>
        <item>Scroll</item>
        <item>Desert</item>
        <item> Magic Blue</item>
        <item>Old City</item>
        <item>Clip Board</item>
        <item>Grass</item>
        <item>Green Leaves</item>
        <item>Moon Landscape</item>
        <item>Prismatic Flourish</item>
        <item>Technologic</item>
        <item>White</item>
        <item>Red</item>
        <item>Blue</item>
        <item>Yellow</item>
    </string-array>
```

is here a best practice to declare a Integer[] in something like array list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can make like this

```
<integer-array name="background_name">
    <item>@drawable/farm_small </item>
</integer-array>
```

You can get it programmatically like this

```
TypedArray bgImgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.background_name);

imgView.setImageResource(bgImgs.getResourceId(0, -1));// Here pass your index
```

Comment: How to pick integer-array in java? I have message that Required: int Found: int[] ?

Comment: @Rodriquez Please see my answer where you can see you can get integer array programatically.

Comment: I can implement this to RecyclerVIew?

Comment: @Rodriquez Certainly :)

Comment: @Rodriquez Please accept answer if you got your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<array name="imageID">
 <item>@drawable/farm_small</item>
 .
 .
 .
   <item>@drawable/farm_smalln</item>
</array>
</resources>
```